# Some errors in my first Django cassandra code

Tags: python, django, cassandra

I want to run my first Django cassandra code in pyCharm.
My code is running smoothly in Django console but it's not working in a .py file. these are the errors:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe "D:/Developer Center/PyCharm/DJangoCassandra/MyApp/testFile.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Developer Center/PyCharm/DJangoCassandra/MyApp/testFile.py", line 3, in <module>
    from MyApp.models import Person
  File "D:\Developer Center\PyCharm\DJangoCassandra\MyApp\models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    if settings.DATABASES and DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS not in settings.DATABASES:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 46, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DATABASES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

this is my .py file:

```
__author__ = 'ehsan'
from cqlengine import connection
from MyApp.models import Person
from cqlengine.management import sync_table,drop_table

def main():
    connection.setup(['127.0.0.1:9160'])
    sync_table(Person)
    Person.create(id='2',name='Ali',family='Rezayee')
    p = Person.objects.all()
    for item in p:
        print item.id
    Person.filter(id='1')
```

this is my model:

```
from django.db import models
from cqlengine import Model, columns
# Create your models here.

class Person(Model):
    id = columns.Text(primary_key=True)
    name = columns.Text()
    family = columns.Text()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Not working in a .py file"? How are you trying to run your code? The error you're getting is due to it being unable to find the settings.py file for your project. The reason it works in Django console is because when you run `manage.py shell` it knows by default where to look for `settings.py`

Answer (score 0):

If you'll write the following lines when starting the `managy.py shell` command, it should work:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "zoo.settings")
```